# Not performed a search by input line

Tags: mysql

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetClients`(
clientPIB NVARCHAR(50),
    pageSize INT,
    pageIndex INT)
    BEGIN
    DECLARE startIndex INT;
    SET startIndex = pageSize * pageIndex;
    SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, MiddleName
    FROM Client 
        WHERE 
        FirstName Like(CASE WHEN clientPIB IS NULL THEN FirstName ELSE '%' + clientPIB + '%' END) OR
        LastName Like(CASE WHEN clientPIB IS NULL THEN LastName ELSE '%' + clientPIB + '%' END) OR
        MiddleName Like(CASE WHEN clientPIB IS NULL THEN MiddleName ELSE '%' + clientPIB + '%' END)
        LIMIT startIndex, pageSize;
    END
```

The table Client has a field
[image]
When I did not specify search criteria, then a name or a name - everything is fine
[image]

But where to start a search on the name or the name of nothing is returned 
[image]

Comment: We don't have enough informations to answer. What's your table's schema? What data are in the table? Which parameters do you try?

Comment: I'm sorry. I corrected my question.

Comment: Instead of `'%' + clientPIB + '%'` try `concat('%', clientPIB, '%')` . If that doesn't work, try to expose the `case` result in your select.

Comment: Great, glad this works for you. I'll convert this comment to an answer, if you don't mind validating it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `'%' + clientPIB + '%'`

Use `concat('%', clientPIB, '%')`

Indeed the + sign is reserved for arithmetic operations.